# R removing extra rows in a matrix compared with another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'll illustrate my question with an example:

```
a1
#     x y
#Adam 1 a
#Mike 2 b
#Mary 3 c

a2
#     i j
#Adam 4 e
#Mary 5 f
```

And what I want is this:

```
a3    x y
#Adam 1 a
#Mary 3 c
```

where the values in a1 don't change, and rows that don't appear in a2 are removed (by rowname only). I searched for quite a while and none of the packages, such as `compare` or `data.frame` worked for me.

I'm totally new to R, and working on quite a large dataset, so please help me with a solution that runs quick :)

Thanks!

Comment: @Gregor Edited. Sorry for the typo! I wanted all the results to be from a1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

```
a3 = a1[rownames(a1) %in% rownames(a2), ]
```

This is pretty simple. We look at which row names from `a1` are also in `a2`, and we keep those rows. It should work whether your data is in a `matrix` or a `data.frame`.

As I commented on the other answer, this could also be viewed as an *inner join* operation. You can do an inner join with `base::merge`, or if you really need speed with the `data.table` or `dplyr` packages. But to use those you will need to convert your matrices to data frames and to add the row names as their own column. If your data really is in a matrix, just using the `rownames()` method I show above will probably be efficient enough.

Answer (score -1):

#### EDITED Answer

`dplyr` only works with `data.frames`.  As such, matrices must be turned into `data.frames`.  You'll need to add a column to the `data.frames` to store the `rownames` from the matrices.

The `by` statement defines which common column(s) of the `data.frame`s to match records on.

```
a1 <- matrix(c(1:3, letters[1:3]),
             nrow = 3,
             dimnames = list(c("Adam", "Mike", "Mary"), c("x", "y")))
a2 <- matrix(c(4:5, letters[4:5]),
             nrow = 2,
             dimnames = list(c("Adam", "Mary"), c("x", "y")))

a1_df <- as.data.frame(a1) %>% dplyr::mutate(rnm = rownames(a1))
a1_df
#   x y  rnm
# 1 1 a Adam
# 2 2 b Mike
# 3 3 c Mary

a2_df <- as.data.frame(a2) %>% dplyr::mutate(rnm = rownames(a2))
a2_df
#   x y  rnm
# 1 4 d Adam
# 2 5 e Mary

dplyr::semi_join(a1_df, a2_df, by = "rnm")
#   x y  rnm
# 1 1 a Adam
# 2 3 c Mary
```

#### Original Answer

Have you used the `anti_join` function in `dplyr`?

> ```
>  ‘anti_join’ return all rows from ‘x’ where there are not matching
>       values in ‘y’, keeping just columns from ‘x’.
> ```

Here is an example.  From what you explain in text, the resulting `data.frame` should only have the "Mike" row.

```
library(dplyr)

a1 <- data.frame(nm = c("Adam", "Mike", "Mary"), x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])
a2 <- data.frame(nm = c("Adam", "Mary"), x = 4:5, y = letters[4:5])

a1
#     nm x y
# 1 Adam 1 a
# 2 Mike 2 b
# 3 Mary 3 c

a2
#     nm x y
# 1 Adam 4 d
# 2 Mary 5 e

anti_join(a1, a2, by = "nm")
#     nm x y
# 1 Mike 2 b
```

Comment: @Gregor, I agree that my solution is not exactly what the OP is looking for, but `a1[rownames(a1) %in% rownames(a2), ]` also fails.  The second row of `a3` comes from `a2`, not `a1`.

Comment: @Peter I sort of went for semi_join during my attempts... and I got `Error in UseMethod("semi_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'semi_join' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"`. I didn't really understand the `by` part of this fuction.

Comment: @Gregor, I'll leave the original answer at the bottom of the post so that readers may reference it when reading our discussion in these comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try the new method out.